# Laravel - display the first image from an array in blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display the first image from this array ["11.jpg","16.jpg"], the array is stored in a table column called images. I am writing

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/properties/'. $files->images) }}" class="">
```

in my blade.php
Nothing appears but it comes with this when I inspect the element

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/properties/["11.jpg","16.jpg"]" class="">
```

I have also tried to display the first item in the array with this code, but the image doesn't appear.
How can I display the first image in blade.php.

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/properties/'. $files->images[0]) }}" class="">
```

Comment: You can use 

 <img src="{{ asset('images/properties/'. $files['images'][0]) }}" >

Comment: It is not showing, this is the result when i inspect the element <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/properties/["> , i want the element to be like this <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/properties/11.jpg">

Comment: what is your array variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow!!! i have found the solution.
The answer is to use json_decode() function.

```
<?php  $property_images = json_decode($files->images);?>
<img src="{{ asset('images/properties/'. $property_images[0]) }}" class="">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use array_first()**

The array_first function returns the first element of an array

You have to store the array using `json_encode`. and while retriving just decode that data using `json_decode`.

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/properties/'. array_first(json_decode($files->images))) }}" />
```

Comment: your code doent work, it shows an ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: first check `array_first($files->images)` in controller is it working or not

Comment: is there any loop in blade ?

Comment: Yes there is a loop

Comment: and are you sure all properties has multiple images  ?

Comment: if any product exisit that has no image or images is null then you have to first check is images is null or array

Comment: The property have multiple images after multiple images upload, one or more images are inserted as an array, and it is a must to upload at least one, so there is no need to check null or array, when retrieving a property, its images are always in an array.

Comment: i got your problem and solution :) Just check updated answer.